# Ubuntu Kernel Boot stuck at "raid6: sse2x1 gen() 858 MB/s"

Tags: linux, ubuntu, boot, kernel, linux-kernel

There is this time skip during *kernel boot*:

```
Jul 19 14:07:02 deetabokkusu kernel: [    2.874776] hub 1-1.4:1.0: USB hub found
Jul 19 14:07:02 deetabokkusu kernel: [    2.877993] hub 1-1.4:1.0: 4 ports detected
Jul 19 14:07:02 deetabokkusu kernel: [   94.080339] raid6: sse2x1   gen()   858 MB/s
Jul 19 14:07:02 deetabokkusu kernel: [   94.128306] raid6: sse2x1   xor()  2371 MB/s
Jul 19 14:07:02 deetabokkusu kernel: [   94.176324] raid6: sse2x2   gen()  1730 MB/s
Jul 19 14:07:02 deetabokkusu kernel: [   94.224328] raid6: sse2x2   xor()  2816 MB/s
Jul 19 14:07:02 deetabokkusu kernel: [   94.272285] raid6: sse2x4   gen()  2430 MB/s
Jul 19 14:07:02 deetabokkusu kernel: [   94.320302] raid6: sse2x4   xor()  2333 MB/s
Jul 19 14:07:02 deetabokkusu kernel: [   94.323121] raid6: using algorithm sse2x4 gen() 2430 MB/s
Jul 19 14:07:02 deetabokkusu kernel: [   94.325949] raid6: .... xor() 2333 MB/s, rmw enabled
Jul 19 14:07:02 deetabokkusu kernel: [   94.328762] raid6: using ssse3x2 recovery algorithm
Jul 19 14:07:02 deetabokkusu kernel: [   94.335698] xor: measuring software checksum speed
Jul 19 14:07:02 deetabokkusu kernel: [   94.376549]    prefetch64-sse:  7668.000 MB/sec
Jul 19 14:07:02 deetabokkusu kernel: [   94.416564]    generic_sse:  6661.000 MB/sec
Jul 19 14:07:02 deetabokkusu kernel: [   94.419385] xor: using function: prefetch64-sse (7668.000 MB/sec)
Jul 19 14:07:02 deetabokkusu kernel: [   94.426733] async_tx: api initialized (async)
Jul 19 14:07:02 deetabokkusu kernel: [   94.555496] Btrfs loaded, crc32c=crc32c-intel
```

I am **not** running a RAID on the system. What do I have to change for the kernel to boot more quickly?

Answer (score 2):

Do you use `btrfs` ? 
If yes, then it's probably not possible to speed up boot since `btrfs` has a strong dependency upon `raid6_pq` code as visible in `modinfo` output:

```
~$ sudo modinfo btrfs
filename:       /lib/modules/4.9.0-9-amd64/kernel/fs/btrfs/btrfs.ko
softdep:        pre: crypto-crc32c
license:        GPL
alias:          devname:btrfs-control
alias:          char-major-10-234
alias:          fs-btrfs
depends:        raid6_pq,xor
retpoline:      Y
intree:         Y
vermagic:       4.9.0-9-amd64 SMP mod_unload modversions
```

If you do not use `btrfs` then  you may simply blacklist the module so that it's not loaded at boot time.
For this, simply create a file `btrfs.conf` in `/etc/modprobe.d` (path may vary depending on your Linux distribution, this path exists for Debian) with the following content:

```
blacklist btrfs
```